# Notepad++ Explorer  plugin is not displaying the last character of file name

Tags: 11.04

I have installed Notepad++ v5.9.3 and Wine v1.3.32

All good except last character of filename (with separate extension) or filename/extension
is truncated in the Explorer panel..

I have un-installed and re-installed Wine, as per a similar question but no good.

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and need assistance to fix this, please
...alanb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine often suffers from these and other problems. The best solution is to switch to an editor that runs in Linux, such as `gedit` or `vim`/`gvim`. There probably isn't an easy way to make Notepad++ work better, short of modifying either Notepad++ or Wine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've actually switched to gedit + plugins and am very happy with it.